# JPA Create Criteria with GROUP COUNT and HAVING on nested objects

Tags: jpa, join, group-by, having

Given this SQL query

```
SELECT
    ug.lookup_key, 
    count(ug.id) as count
FROM user u
INNER JOIN user_group ug on ug.id = u.id
WHERE 
    u.age >= 11 AND 
    u.age <= 20 AND
    ug.lookup_key in('12345')
GROUP BY ug.lookup_key
HAVING count(ug.id) < 7
```

I have written this

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<UserGroup> d = query.from(UserGroup.class);
Join<UserGroup, User> join = d.join("users");

Predicate pred1 = criteriaBuilder.between(join.get("age"), ageFrom, ageTo);
Expression<String> exp = d.get("lookupKey");
Predicate pred2 = exp.in(lookupKeys);

query.where(pred1, pred2);

query.multiselect(d.get("lookupKey"), criteriaBuilder.count(d.get("id"))).groupBy(d.get("lookupKey"));

List<Object[]> results = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();

for(Object[] object : results){
    System.out.println(object[0] + " " + object[1]);
}
```

The SQL returns {"12345",4} whereas the code returns {"12345", 37}. The SQL is the correct result. There are 37 users in the database for groups with that lookup key, so I understand where the numbers are coming from but I do not understand how to do the JOIN, GROUP BY, HAVING with the CreateCriteria query so that I get the results. I don't want to use JPQL.

The entities...

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private int age;

    private double salary;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false,cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=UserGroup.class)
    @JsonBackReference
    private UserGroup group;

    // Getters and Setters //

}

@Entity
public class UserGroup {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private String lookupKey;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="group",targetEntity=User.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Collection users;

    // Getters and Setters //

}
```

And also, here is the method in which it is implemented

```
public void summarizeGroupsByLookupKey(long ageFrom, long ageTo, List<String> lookupKeys, long numUsers){
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object[].class);
        Root<UserGroup> d = query.from(UserGroup.class);
        Join<UserGroup, User> join = d.join("users");

        Predicate pred1 = criteriaBuilder.between(join.get("age"), ageFrom, ageTo);
        Expression<String> exp = d.get("lookupKey");
        Predicate pred2 = exp.in(lookupKeys);

        query.where(pred1, pred2);
        query.multiselect(d.get("lookupKey"), criteriaBuilder.count(d.get("id")));
        query.groupBy(d.get("lookupKey"));
        query.having(criteriaBuilder.<Long>lessThan(criteriaBuilder.count(d.get("id")), numUsers));

        List<Object[]> results = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();

        for(Object[] object : results){
            System.out.println(object[0] + " " + object[1]);
        }
    }
```

By way of info...using Spring Boot 1.5.1 and all the default JPA, Hibernate, etc. from there.

Can a JPA expert offer some help? Thanks!

Comment: can you share `User` & `UserGroup` entities?

Comment: Edited answer to include them

Answer (score 0):

Change the multiselect part to use `countDistinct(..)`

```
query.multiselect(d.get("lookupKey")
      ,criteriaBuilder.countDistinct(d.get("id")));
```

and also `having(..)`

```
query.having(criteriaBuilder.<Long>lessThan(
                   criteriaBuilder.countDistinct(d.get("id")), numUsers)
                );
```

Original query returned row per matching user in which rows `userGroup.id` was then multiplied.

Comment: Yes - the intention is for the query to be inclusive. I updated the SQL. I also implemented the having clause as you mentioned, but it still returned {"12345",37} when it should return {"12345",4}. It's something with the way the join() is setup - I just don't know what it is.

Comment: @jmorhardt Well what can I say... Your code works fine with me. The having-clause of course has nothing to do with the count you get.  Did you test this with hard coded attributes / logged the attributes you pass? I did remove `targetEntity=...` from mappings because not needed but otherwise should be exactly the same.

Comment: I've been debugging it in IntelliJ IDEA. Definitely confirmed that the parameters are as expected. Do you have a sample of your code? Maybe I can spot a difference. I'll add the whole method in a moment.

Comment: Code exact copy of yours except mentioned. Not able to paste it now but will as soon as back in the office tomorrow.

Comment: @jmorhardt Copy-pasted your `summarizeGroupsByLookupKey(..)` and it passes my tests. But I do not have **your data**. Only addition is that - because using Postgres reserved word _USER_ - added `@Table(name="\"user\"")` to `User` but it should not matter. Maybe I ahve totally misunderstood your problem. Maybe you should paste that 37 rows of users to teh question, tell what rows og those you want to see and tell what JPA provider & db using?

Comment: I'm using the standard JDBC connector for MySQL. What I am trying to do is get the count of UserGroups that have users in a certain age range, grouped by the lookupKey. IOW, with my data, I am expecting that 4 UserGroups with users in the specified age range share the same lookupKey ("12345").

Comment: Yes. I misunderstood. I should have been more careful when studying your SQL. I'll check my answer. The query of yours returns now the amount of user in age interval grouped by  group (with that having...).